# Recover luks partition for /home after system erase - cant mount /dev/mapper/MyDevice

Tags: debian, lvm, luks

I looked on a lot of places and cant find what to do now.

I had encrypted /home on 2nd hard drive. I had to format my debian and now want to access my data.

```
sudo fdisk -l 
/dev/sda1  *       2048    194559    192512    94M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        196606   4100095   3903490   1,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       4100096 625141759 621041664 296,1G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5        196608   4100095   3903488   1,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

sda3 is for /home.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksopen /dev/sda3 test
```

Ask for passphrase : passphrase is ok

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/test /mnt/test
```

unknown file system type, bad option or wrong superblock on /dev/mapper/test , missing codepage...

**EDIT :**

```
 sudo vgscan -vvvv
#lvmcmdline.c:1346     DEGRADED MODE. Incomplete RAID LVs will be processed.
#libdm-config.c:941       Setting activation/monitoring to 1
#lvmcmdline.c:1352         Processing: vgscan -vvvv
#lvmcmdline.c:1355         O_DIRECT will be used
#libdm-config.c:877       Setting global/locking_type to 1
#libdm-config.c:941       Setting global/wait_for_locks to 1
#locking/locking.c:128       File-based locking selected.
#libdm-config.c:941       Setting global/prioritise_write_locks to 1
#libdm-config.c:846       Setting global/locking_dir to /run/lock/lvm
#misc/lvm-flock.c:200       Locking /run/lock/lvm/P_global WB
#misc/lvm-flock.c:101         _do_flock /run/lock/lvm/P_global:aux WB
#misc/lvm-flock.c:101         _do_flock /run/lock/lvm/P_global WB
#misc/lvm-flock.c:48         _undo_flock /run/lock/lvm/P_global:aux
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#global"
#filters/filter-persistent.c:52     Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sda: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST320LT020-9YG142_W04248X5: Aliased to /dev/sda in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500449d779a: Aliased to /dev/sda in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sda1: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST320LT020-9YG142_W04248X5-part1: Aliased to /dev/sda1 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500449d779a-part1: Aliased to /dev/sda1 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-uuid/ead2584b-d4cd-42b8-abe4-954b57081066: Aliased to /dev/sda1 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sda2: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST320LT020-9YG142_W04248X5-part2: Aliased to /dev/sda2 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500449d779a-part2: Aliased to /dev/sda2 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sda3: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST320LT020-9YG142_W04248X5-part3: Aliased to /dev/sda3 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500449d779a-part3: Aliased to /dev/sda3 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-uuid/cc2f047f-b62b-4af9-86a1-9623b91f6712: Aliased to /dev/sda3 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sda5: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST320LT020-9YG142_W04248X5-part5: Aliased to /dev/sda5 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500449d779a-part5: Aliased to /dev/sda5 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-uuid/bcd71a27-76e4-47bf-84f1-2df2bd970212: Aliased to /dev/sda5 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sdb: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SATA_SSD_1116071912042B2E8F03: Aliased to /dev/sdb in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/sdb1: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SATA_SSD_1116071912042B2E8F03-part1: Aliased to /dev/sdb1 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-uuid/f76544b3-fc2a-45e6-a8bd-a6c3d56ab4a4: Aliased to /dev/sdb1 in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop0: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop1: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:321         /dev/disk/by-uuid/cc2f047f-b62b-4af9-86a1-9623b91f6712: Already in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop2: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop3: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop4: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop5: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop6: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/loop7: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:335         /dev/dm-0: Added to device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-test: Aliased to /dev/dm-0 in device cache (preferred name)
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS1-cc2f047fb62b4af986a19623b91f6712-test: Aliased to /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-test in device cache
#device/dev-cache.c:332         /dev/mapper/test: Aliased to /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-test in device cache (preferred name)
#cache/lvmcache.c:1626     Wiping internal VG cache
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#global"
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#orphans_lvm1"
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#orphans_lvm1"
#cache/lvmcache.c:1354         lvmcache: initialised VG #orphans_lvm1
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#orphans_pool"
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#orphans_pool"
#cache/lvmcache.c:1354         lvmcache: initialised VG #orphans_pool
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#orphans_lvm2"
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#orphans_lvm2"
#cache/lvmcache.c:1354         lvmcache: initialised VG #orphans_lvm2
#vgscan.c:61   Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
#toollib.c:679     Finding all volume groups
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop0 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop0: size is 621039679 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop0
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop0: size is 621039679 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop0 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/loop0: block size is 512 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/loop0: physical block size is 512 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop0
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/loop0
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop0 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/loop0: block size is 512 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/loop0: physical block size is 512 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/loop0: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop0
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda: size is 625142448 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:45         /dev/sda: Skipping: Partition table signature found
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda
#ioctl/libdm-iface.c:1768         dm version   OF   [16384] (*1)
#ioctl/libdm-iface.c:1768         dm status   (254:0) OF   [16384] (*1)
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/mapper/test RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/mapper/test: size is 621037568 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/mapper/test
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/mapper/test: size is 621037568 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/mapper/test RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/mapper/test: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/mapper/test: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/mapper/test
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/mapper/test
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/mapper/test RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/mapper/test: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/mapper/test: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/mapper/test: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/mapper/test
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop1: size is 621041664 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop1
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop1: size is 621041664 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/loop1: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/loop1: physical block size is 512 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop1
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/loop1
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/loop1: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/loop1: physical block size is 512 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/loop1: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop1
#filters/filter-mpath.c:166         /dev/sda1: Device is a partition, using primary device sda for mpath component detection
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda1: size is 192512 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda1
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda1: size is 192512 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda1: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda1: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda1
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/sda1
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda1: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda1: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/sda1: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda1
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop2 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop2: size is 0 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/loop2: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop2
#filters/filter-mpath.c:166         /dev/sda2: Device is a partition, using primary device sda for mpath component detection
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda2 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda2: size is 2 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/sda2: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda2
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop3 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop3: size is 0 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/loop3: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop3
#filters/filter-mpath.c:166         /dev/sda3: Device is a partition, using primary device sda for mpath component detection
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda3 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda3: size is 621041664 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda3
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda3: size is 621041664 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda3 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda3: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda3: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda3
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/sda3
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda3 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda3: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda3: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/sda3: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda3
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop4 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop4: size is 0 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/loop4: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop4
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop5 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop5: size is 0 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/loop5: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop5
#filters/filter-mpath.c:166         /dev/sda5: Device is a partition, using primary device sda for mpath component detection
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda5 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda5: size is 3903488 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda5
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sda5: size is 3903488 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda5 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda5: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda5: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda5
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/sda5
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sda5 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sda5: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sda5: physical block size is 4096 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/sda5: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sda5
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop6 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop6: size is 0 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/loop6: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop6
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/loop7 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/loop7: size is 0 sectors
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:39         /dev/loop7: Skipping: Too small to hold a PV
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/loop7
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sdb RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sdb: size is 39091248 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sdb: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sdb: physical block size is 512 bytes
#filters/filter-partitioned.c:45         /dev/sdb: Skipping: Partition table signature found
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sdb
#filters/filter-mpath.c:166         /dev/sdb1: Device is a partition, using primary device sdb for mpath component detection
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sdb1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sdb1: size is 39088128 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sdb1
#device/dev-io.c:313       /dev/sdb1: size is 39088128 sectors
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sdb1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sdb1: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sdb1: physical block size is 512 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sdb1
#device/dev-cache.c:1048         Using /dev/sdb1
#device/dev-io.c:536         Opened /dev/sdb1 RO O_DIRECT
#device/dev-io.c:144         /dev/sdb1: block size is 4096 bytes
#device/dev-io.c:155         /dev/sdb1: physical block size is 512 bytes
#label/label.c:179       /dev/sdb1: No label detected
#label/label.c:282         <backtrace>
#device/dev-io.c:590         Closed /dev/sdb1
#toollib.c:683   No volume groups found
#misc/lvm-flock.c:71       Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/P_global
#misc/lvm-flock.c:48         _undo_flock /run/lock/lvm/P_global
#cache/lvmcache.c:438         Metadata cache has no info for vgname: "#global"
#lvmcmdline.c:1413         Completed: vgscan -vvvv
```

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sda3` is of type `Linux LVM`. You can't mount this directly. You have to scan first for (a) `volume group(s) (vg)` and after this mount the appropriate `logical volume (lv)`. Please issue `vgscan`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` (in this order) and post the output.

**Edit 1:** Please run `pvscan` and afterwards `vgscan`. Whats the output?

**Edit 2:** Please run `vgscan -vvvv` and post the output.

Comment: For all three commands, i get "no volume groups found"

Comment: Please see my "Edit 1".

Comment: No matching physical volumes found for pvscan and no volume groups found for vgscan

Comment: Please see my "Edit 2".